# Create array of simpler JSON objects from a nested JSON using jolt

Tags: json, jolt

My input JSON is like

```json
{
  "common": {
    "name": "abc"
  },
  "details": {
    "id": 4,
    "node": [
      {
        "name": "node1",
        "array2": []
      },
      {
        "name": "node2",
        "array2": [
          {
            "name": "node2_a2_1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "node3",
        "array2": [
          {
            "name": "node3_a2_1"
          },
          {
            "name": "node3_a2_2"
          },
          {
            "name": "node3_a2_3"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I want is for each leaf node in array2 (e.g. `{"name": "node3_a2_1"}`) I will traverse towards the root and add all common items and create an array of JSON objects without any nested object. So, the output I want is like

```json
[
  {
    "common_name": "abc",
    "id": 4,
    "node_name": "node2",
    "name": "node2_a2_1"
  },
  {
    "common_name": "abc",
    "id": 4,
    "node_name": "node3",
    "name": "node3_a2_1"
  },
  {
    "common_name": "abc",
    "id": 4,
    "node_name": "node3",
    "name": "node3_a2_2"
  },
  {
    "common_name": "abc",
    "id": 4,
    "node_name": "node3",
    "name": "node3_a2_3"
  }
]
```

Could you please suggest how can I do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can walk through the `array2` while picking values of each element from their original location in the JSON value.

For example; traverse `}` four times to grab the value of `id` by using `@(4,id)`, and use `@(3,name)[&1]` as the common distinguishing identifier for each attribute such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "details": {
        "node": {
          "*": {
            "array2": {
              "*": {
                "@(5,common.name)": "@(3,name)[&1].common_name",
                "@(4,id)": "@(3,name)[&1].id",
                "@(2,name)": "@(3,name)[&1].node_name",
                "name": "@(3,name)[&1].&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]